# accessing html within an html document

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to do some video processing on html5 video in a webpage using JavaScript.  This is possible when the video tag is in the same document.  What I am doing is seeing if it is possible when forcing html5 video through a third party player.  The video tag is there, but it is nested inside new HTML tags.  When using `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];` to set a variable to the video object I am getting `undefined` which leads me to believe I cannot access the video in this way.  I am not very experienced with HTML or especially JavaScript (I'm an intern kind of getting thrown into the deep end).  Is there some way I need to tell the JavaScript to look for the video tag specifically within the HTML tags that are inserted into my base document?

Here is the code that I am trying to access...it is inside the body of the html document where my script resides that is trying to access it...the first object is a first child of the main documents body element...I left out some unimportant style stuff but that is the video I want to grab and assign to a js variable:

```
<object id="kaltura_player" .......application type = "shockwave-flash"....unimportant style stuff>

    <html>
        <head> <title>test_inter1_xvid_2min_800.webm</title> </head>
        <body>
            <video autoplay="" controls="" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 100%; height: 100%" tabindex="0"></video>
        <body>
    </html>
 </object>
```

Comment: How are these video tags being inserted? Are you running your script AFTER they're added, or at page load?

Comment: @Diodeus I am still not totally sure as to how they are added.  What I can say is that we use an external player that usually inserts a flash object and then these external scripts are somehow forcing it to output html5 video.  To ensure that the video tags are already added I fire my video processing script from a button so I can visually confirm that the video has been added and is also playing.  But again, the inserted video tags are within new html tags inside the original page.  Is it possible to access elements within an internal html element from the original html document?

Comment: also can you please share your html tags ?

Comment: added the html of concern...keep in mind this is within the body of the original html code where my script will be working from .

Comment: Update: I found out that I can access embedded html document from the original document by creating a simple test.  Now the question has turned into "can I do this if the html is being injected by a script that is on a different server".  I suppose I will answer this question and open a new one that is more appropriate for that part of my question after I research it on my own of course ;).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question incase anyone can get use from this post still.  Yes you can access embedded html from your script within the base html.  But I have yet to find out why I can't access mine but I suppose it has to do with the html being injected from a different domain.  I will look into this.

Comment: I don't see how that would be a problem (that the script injecting the HTML is served from a different domain). Regardless of where the script is loaded from the end result is that your DOM is changed. Doesn't matter if an external script changed it or not. The second it's in your DOM you should be able to access it.